# CSS3 FLEXBOX, left and right floating items

Tags: css, flexbox

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item" style='width:15%'>flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item" style='width:15%'>flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item" style='width:15%'>flex item 3</div> 
</div>
```

In above example i want Item1 on left side, and, item 2 and 3 on right side of page using CSS3 Flexbox.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What CSS do you currently have? How is it not working?

Comment: .flex-container{ display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
   }

Comment: @prasadparab https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ this could help you.

Comment: @Parth thanks for the link. bt that link doesn't contain my required scenario

Comment: Just apply `margin-right: auto` to item one, or `margin-left: auto` to item two. Either one does the job. See boxes #26 and #31 in the duplicate.

Answer (score 20):

https://jsfiddle.net/y9o1utqk/

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
  <span></span>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div> 
</div>

.flex-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  border:2px blue solid;
}

.flex-container > span{
  flex-grow:1; 
}

.flex-container > .flex-item{
  border:2px red solid;
  flex-grow:0;
  width:15%;
}
```

alternatively:

https://jsfiddle.net/y9o1utqk/1/

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="left">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="flex-item">flex item 2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div> 
  </div>
</div>

.flex-item{
  border:4px red solid;
  flex-grow:0;
  width:15%;
}

.flex-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  border:4px blue solid;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.flex-container > .left{
  width:15%;
  border:4px red solid;
}

.flex-container > .right{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  border:4px lime solid;
  width:30%;
}

.flex-container > .right > div{
  border:4px red solid;
  width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Yes.. this is waht i want. But, can u plz tell me why u added d extra span?Is it possible to do without span?

Comment: it's what separates the left from the right. i'm posting another solution. check it out